# Lot of Apache requests in "L" state, what could be the reason? DDOS?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, ddos

I am having this in my apache server status message:

LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLWLLLLLLLLWLLLLLWLLLLLLLLLLWLLLLLLLWLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
WLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLWLWLLLLLLLLL
LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLWLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLRLLWLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
LLLLLLLWLLLWLWLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLWLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLWLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
LLLLWRLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
LWLLLLLLLLWLLLLLWLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLWLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLWLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLWLWL
LLLWLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLWLLLLLLLLLWLL

What could be its reason? all of the 512 slots were filled and requests per second was only 3. CPU load got to 250+ (15m).
is it some kind of DDOS ? as lot of requests were just GET requests to lot many different virtual hosts with different IP addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rather implies that it's taking much longer for apache to log a requset than to receive, process and send a response. Which seems improbable. It's more likely that you've got a problem with your filesystem.

(it would have been helpful if you supplied the full output of server-status)

Next step would be to have a log at the syslog - see if there's problems on your hardware. If it's still occurring, check the output of iotop. If these show nothing amiss then have a look at your webserver logs (access *and* error).

It might just be that you [haven't rotated your logs](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/servers/156542-apache-many-threads-stuck-logging-status.html) for too long.

Comment: This answer is definitely correct. One place to look is if you're using some special ErrorLog/CustomLog entries to send httpd logs to a central syslog server. In my case the syslog server was processing the input slowly which caused apache to slow down.